# ContourPlot using ElementMeshSurfacePlot3D

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, finite-element-method

I would like to add contours for iso-level values of a FEM solution of a PDE on a generic 3D region; for visualization of values on the boundary, I have used `ElementMeshSurfacePlot3D` in the `` NDSolve`FEM`​ `` package (as in the Wolfram example of the [Space Shuttle](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/solve-pdes-over-3d-regions.html)). The 3D region is an oil pump taken from CAD and imported using STL format.

I would like to insert into the 3D graphics the contour lines for some values of the temperature on the boundary.

[image: pump]

Answer (score 9):

You could use [`SliceContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceContourPlot3D.html).  Using the definitions of `mr` and `uif` from the page linked in the OP (and defined in user21's answer),

```
SliceContourPlot3D[
 uif[x, y, z], {mr}, {x, -8, 8}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -2, 5}, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

`ElementMeshSurfacePlot3D` does not have an option to plot contours in Version 10. It may get one in the future. One thing you can do is use the function `imsFindContour` form [this old, outdated package](https://github.com/ruebenko/IMS). You'll find the function in the file [UnstructuredPlot.m](https://github.com/ruebenko/IMS/blob/master/Imtek/UnstructuredPlot.m)

Then you can do something like this:

```
mr = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "SpaceShuttle"}]];
uif = NDSolveValue[{Inactive[Laplacian][u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 1, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 1, z <= -1.3]}, 
   u, {x, y, z} \[Element] mr];

Get["Imtek`UnstructuredPlot`"] // Quiet
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

mesh = uif["ElementMesh"];
Show[
 ElementMeshSurfacePlot3D[uif, Boxed -> False, 
  ViewPoint -> {0, -4, 2}],
 Graphics3D[
  Polygon /@ 
     imsFindContour[mesh["Coordinates"], 
       Join @@ ElementIncidents[mesh["BoundaryElements"]], 
       uif["ValuesOnGrid"], #][[All, -1]] & /@ 
   Range[Sequence @@ MinMax[uif["ValuesOnGrid"]], 2], Boxed -> False]
 ]
```

[image]

Not perfect but maybe a starting point.

Comment: Would contours on a surface plot be a feature that is generally of interest to people doing FEM with Mathematica?

Comment: Well, that, or more generally the ability to specify a `MeshFunction` on a plot over a region. BTW: you can do `ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "SpaceShuttle"}, "BoundaryMeshRegion"]` instead.

Comment: Dear JasonB and user21, thanks for your answers. Do you have an example on using MeshFunction for level set PDE solution data on a 3D region as shuttle? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks also to J.M., sorry; J.M., I ask you too about my previous question on MeshFunction.

Comment: @GianlucaArgentini, that's a new question, and please provide code in your questions showing what you tried so far.

Comment: I try to draw a set of contours level lines on a 3D surface having a list {..., {x,y,z,temp[x,y,z]} of points and their temperature value; it is possible to use a 3D graphics visualization using and instruction to MeshFunctions for  visualize e.i. 5 levels based on temperature values?

Comment: @GianlucaArgentini, it's best to ask a new question with an example explaining what you are looking for.

Comment: @user21 how to extract the boundary from the `ElementMesh`?

Comment: @IceOcean use `mesh["BoundaryElements"]`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to your answers and help, I have obtained the graphical effect that I wanted whis this code, where temperature[x,y,z] is the solution from NDSolve on body pump:

RegionPlot3D[Import["pump.stl", MeshFunctions -> {temperature[x,y,z]}, Mesh -> 10, 
 MeshShading -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"] /@ Range[0, 1, 1/(mesh + 1)], PlotPoints -> 20]

and this is the result:
[image]